# node.js expressjs proxy static from amazon s3

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, knox-amazon-s3-client

When a request comes in for a page, eg `app.get("/")` I want to return a static HTML page from amazon s3. I know I can request it from S3 and then send it, but that seems slow. Is there anyway to tell the requester to get the file from s3 directly without changing the url?

Thanks.

Failing that, what's the fastest way to serve the file from s3?

This tutorial shows writing the file first

http://www.hacksparrow.com/node-js-amazon-s3-how-to-get-started.html

```
// We need the fs module so that we can write the stream to a file
var fs = require('fs');
// Set the file name for WriteStream
var file = fs.createWriteStream('slash-s3.jpg');
knox.getFile('slash.jpg', function(err, res) {
    res.on('data', function(data) { file.write(data); });
    res.on('end', function(chunk) { file.end(); });
});
```

Is there a way to send the file without writing it first? Writing it seems awfully slow.

Comment: I believe the only 3 options is: 1) `iframe`; 2) cache html; 3) redirect. Maybe you could serve it with reverse proxy (like nginx) and let html be cached in user's browser.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you suspected, you cannot get the requester to fetch from S3 directly without changing the URL. You have to proxy the remote page:

```
var http = require('http'),
    express = require('express'),
    app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  http.get('http://www.stackoverflow.com', function(proxyRes) {
    proxyRes.pipe(res);
  });
});

app.listen(8080);
```

You can cache the remote page for better performance.

Comment: I believe this redirect changes the url and messes up relative links?

Comment: Yes, HTTP redirects always change the visible URL (I've just tested with 301, 302, 303 and 307). I'll update my answer with the proxy solution.

Comment: In the proxy solution, will the user be able to find out the URL of the S3?

Comment: Nope, the file will appear as originating from your server.

Comment: will this respond correctly when the browser has cached the request before and you should send 304 not modified?

Comment: Actually, I don't think so, since you're streaming the response, I don't think Express can check it before you've sent everything. You'd have to compare the Etag returned by S3 with the one provided by the client before streaming anything.

Answer (score 0):

If the s3 page is truly static (e.g. changes rarely) your server could certainly load it the first time it was requested and cache it; that wouldn't cause any appreciable slowdown.

Otherwise, I'd rethink the "without changing the URL" requirement; the most common "solutions" are hacks generally involving frames.